# Add "blink" effect to mapbox pin

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to add a "blink" animation to all my new pins, like in this sample
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image-animated/

Idea:
1. new pin appears on the map
2. show blink animation for one second
3. static pin remains on the map

My attempts:
I tried to rework the solution above. But is shows and stops animations for all pins on the map at the same time and I can't to control it separately.

Here is my draft code, but I believe I'm doing it definitely not in the right wayЖ

```
  var index = 0;
        var ids = 0;
        var animations = [];

        var pulsingDot = {
                width: size,
                height: size,
                data: new Uint8Array(size * size * 4),

                // get rendering context for the map canvas when layer is added to the map
                onAdd: function () {
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    canvas.width = this.width;
                    canvas.height = this.height;
                    this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                    ids++;

                    this.id = ids;
                    animations[this.id] = -1;
                },

                // called once before every frame where the icon will be used
                render: function (x) {
                    debugger
                    var duration = 1000;
                    var t = (performance.now() % duration) / duration;

                    var radius = (size / 2) * 0.3;
                    var outerRadius = (size / 2) * 0.7 * t + radius;
                    var context = this.context;

                    if(animations[this.id] == 1){
                        outerRadius = (size / 2) * 0.7 + radius;
                    }

                    console.log(outerRadius, t)

                    // draw outer circle
                    context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.arc(
                        this.width / 2,
                        this.height / 2,
                        outerRadius,
                        0,
                        Math.PI * 2
                    );
                    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 200, 200,' + (1 - t) + ')';


                    if (animations[this.id] == 1) {
                        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 200, 200, 0)';
                    }

                    context.fill();

                    // draw inner circle
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.arc(
                        this.width / 2,
                        this.height / 2,
                        radius,
                        0,
                        Math.PI * 2
                    );
                    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 100, 100, 1)';
                    context.strokeStyle = 'white';
                    context.lineWidth = 2 + 4 * (1 - t);
                    context.fill();
                    context.stroke();

                    // update this image's data with data from the canvas
                    this.data = context.getImageData(
                        0,
                        0,
                        this.width,
                        this.height
                    ).data;

                    // continuously repaint the map, resulting in the smooth animation of the dot

                    if(animations[this.id] != 2){
                        map.triggerRepaint();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (animations[this.id] == -1 && outerRadius > 45) {

                        animations[this.id] = 0;
                    }
                    else if (animations[this.id] == 0 && outerRadius > 45) {

                        animations[this.id] = 1;
                    }
                    else if (animations[this.id] == 1) {
                        animations[this.id] = 2;
                    }




                    // return `true` to let the map know that the image was updated
                    return true;
                }
            };
```

Comment: Read this [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If all of your new pins are in the same [source](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/source/), added visually with the same [layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/layer/), then this is expected behavior. To apply different visual behaviors to points represented by features, you will either need to add the points as separate sources each with their own layer, or add a unique ID property to each feature in the source so that the corresponding layer can use a [filter](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/filter/) to apply the desired visual styling to each point.

Since the code you shared in the original post doesn't show how the pulsing dot icons are actually being added to the map using sources and layers, it would be helpful if you could create minimal [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) which shows the behavior you are describing for a few test points.